# XmlWriter stops writing to StringBuilder

Tags: c#, stringbuilder, xmlwriter

I have a strange problem. When looping through an array and creating XML with XMLWriter and a StringBuilder the strings just stop getting added to the string builder. I don't get any errors until the XmlDoc.LoadXml method is called when I get this error:

Unexpected end of file has occurred. The following elements are not closed: ID, Port, Ports. Line 1256, position 39.

When I stepped though the code the loops continue and throw no errors but nothing is added to the string builder.

Any Ideas? Thanks

```
public XmlElement LclExportGetPorts()
    {
        DAL.DALSoapClient soapy = new DAL.DALSoapClient();
        DAL.DALStringString[] ports = soapy.EnumPortsWeb(false);
        XmlDocument XmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        StringBuilder SB = new StringBuilder();
        XmlWriterSettings XmlSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        XmlSettings.Indent = true;
        using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(SB, XmlSettings))
        {
            writer.WriteStartDocument();
            writer.WriteStartElement("Ports");
            foreach (var p in ports)
            {
                writer.WriteStartElement("Port");
                writer.WriteElementString("ID", p.Key);
                writer.WriteElementString("Name", p.Value);
                writer.WriteEndElement();
            }
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.WriteEndDocument();
            string temp = writer.ToString();
            XmlDoc.LoadXml(SB.ToString());
        }
        XmlElement Result = XmlDoc.DocumentElement;
        return Result;
    }
```

Comment: Is there some reason you can't just programmatically create the xml document?  It would probably be more efficient, parsing is expensive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think working with Linq2Xml is much more easier. (Also no need to form an xml string first and then parsing it as `Wug` suggested)

```
public XElement LclExportGetPorts()
{
    ......
    XElement xDoc = new XElement("Ports");
    foreach (var p in ports)
    {
        xDoc.Add(new XElement("Port", new XElement("ID", p.ID), 
                                      new XElement("Name", p.Name)));
    }
    return xDoc;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to `Flush()` the writer.